# Django 1.8 ModelForm request.POST supersedes instance

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I'm working with the Django 1.8 Alpha codebase and wanted to see if anyone else was running into this funny issue. I have a ModelForm:

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birthday', 'avatar')
```

And I also have my view:

```
@login_required
def edit_child(request, id):
    """Edit a child"""
    child = get_object_or_404(Child, pk=id)

    if not child.parent == request.user:
        raise Http404()

    form = ChildForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=child)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('dashboard')

    context = {
        'child': child,
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'edit_child.html', context)
```

When I render the form in the template, everything works fine minus one thing. The initial values are empty. In past versions of Django, using both `request.POST` with `instance=child` allows the instance to shine through and fill the form. But for some odd reason it seems to be accepting request.POST as the initial state rather than the instance. In debugging:

- The form is bound
- The initial data in the form is set correctly
- The instance is set correctly

The only issue is the rendering. For the sake of show, here's my template using crispy_forms for the form rendering:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ child.get_edit_url }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

Anyone see this before or see something that I'm clearly doing wrong?

Comment: Normally you would not pass request.POST to the form unless it actually was a post.

Comment: @DanielRoseman in some cases, yes you could define the form after checking for POST, but Django allows you to do this as a quicker more clean solution as you can see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: I'm not sure what that link is supposed to be showing me. There they are using the POST data to instantiate the form prior to saving it. You should not pass the data for initial display; apart from anything else it binds it and triggers validation, so you will get any errors on first display which is rarely what you want.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's not how it works. In essence, it's a dictionary merge where request.POST = {} on a GET request and the instance itself has all of the defined keys and value. So on the GET request, nothing is overridden but when a POST request comes through then the relevant keys are updated. The idea is that if there are errors, you want the instance and the updated post data to be combined for the user. Or so I believe. The link was more or less a way to show that it's a Django "thing" to initialize forms that way.

Comment: The merge happens with the `initial` dict, not with `data` or `files`. Your form is considered bound if either one of `data` and `files` [`is not None`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8a1/django/forms/forms.py#L117). If a certain key is missing from `data` while the form is bound, it is considered explicitly deleted by the user, so it will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that I needed to explicitly set `None` if a dict was returned for **BOTH** files and post data:

```
form = ChildForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=child)
```

Carry on.